# Scaramucci Interviews on TV

Tags: united-states, media

Does anyone know why Scaramucci, who is a businessman, is invited for interviews on TV for political discussions?

Answer (score 7):

Anthony Scaramucci briefly served as the White House Director of Communications in the Trump administration for 10 days from July 21 to July 31, 2017. He also served on Mitt Romney’s campaign and Trump’s Presidential Transition Team Executive Committee. So he has *some* political experience and a connection to the Trump administration.

To expand on why this gets him on TV: Scaramucci is not invited on a show if the producers want in-depth political analysis, he’s invited if they want someone charismatic and attention-grabbing who is willing to opine about politics, specifically with respect to Trump. He can call on his (pre-employment) relationship with Trump and his (limited) experience in the Trump Administration to provide “inside knowledge” of the Trump Administration or Trump’s actions.

Is he qualified to do this? That’s a matter of opinion (mine would be that he is not), but that doesn’t really matter since his role is not to be an expert.

Comment: He's also at least mildly notorious, which is the cable news channel television version of clickbait. Whether or not these are *good* reasons for him to be booked for interviews so often...

Comment: @divibisan, I guess I do not understand why 10 days experience is worth of that much airtime.
Also, both him and his boss got there not because they deserve it or know how to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Like his former boss, he's good on TV. He was an official, so professional media has no ethical issue with inviting him on to discuss the Trump admin. Combine that experience with his dynamic personality, brashness, and willingness to criticize the president, and you have a somewhat unique TV personality. Lastly, he makes himself available for these roles, whereas many former Trump admin officials are more reserved.